# property value becomes when Backgrounworker Do-work executes

Tags: c#, .net

i want to share files to social medias. i have taken the list of files and set that into an application object property the list of files value was in applicationobject when the form_Load executes.i have called backgroungworker in form_load In dowork i asked to perform some operation with the method called from another class.when dowork executes iam not having value in application object.

here is my code

```
 private CloudBuddyApp applicationObject;
        public CloudBuddyApp ApplicationObject
        {
            get { return applicationObject; }
            set { applicationObject = value; }
        }

 enum ProcessType
        {
            PublicAcess
        }
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                processtype = ProcessType.PublicAcess;
                uxbackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
             }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                CloudBuddyLog.WriteErrorInfo("Share.cs :: Form1_Load :" + error.Message);
            }

         }
 private void uxbackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)/// when it executes the count becomes zero in application
        {
            //try
            //{
                switch (processtype)
                {
                    case ProcessType.PublicAcess:
                        presenter.GetPublicURL();
                    break;
                }
            //}
            //catch(Exception error)
            //{
            //    CloudBuddyLog.WriteErrorInfo("Share.cs :: uxbackgroundWorker_DoWork:" + error.Message);
            //}
        }

        private void uxbackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (processtype)
                {
                    case ProcessType.PublicAcess:
                        presenter.setdata();
                        uxCommentTextBox.Text = generatedurl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                CloudBuddyLog.WriteErrorInfo("Share.cs :: uxbackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted:" + error.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: you are not setting the value of ApplicationObject anywhere in your Form_Load

Comment: i do not understand your code. it even does not compile.

Comment: Why you don't asking a question?. "how?" or "why?". How you suppose to be taken the answer, if you even didn't ask why?